# Install outline VPN on a NAT VPS

Tags: vpn, firewall, vps, nat

I'm trying to install outline on my NAT server, but I keep getting this error:

> Your Outline Server was installed correctly, but we are not able to connect to it. Most likely this is because your server's firewall rules are blocking incoming connections. Please review them and make sure to allow incoming TCP connections on ports ranging from 1024 to 65535.

I can only use 22801 to 22820 ports since I have a NAT VPS. How can I force outline to not generate a random API port or how can I install outline using my given ports?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo bash -c "$(wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-server/master/src/server_manager/install_scripts/install_server.sh)" install_server.sh --api-port=xxxx --keys-port=xxx
```